# SQL query with duplicate records

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query in SQL server to find out if there are any multiple rows for each customer by customerID.
Please let me know.

Here is the table structure

```
Customer table
-----------------------------------------
orderID          CustName      CustomerID
---------------------------------------
100               test           123456    
101               test           123456

Orders table
------------------------------------
pID               OrderID
-----------------------------------
1                 100        
2                 101
```

Comment: If you're in a place to alter the design, please note that you your question arises from the existence of 'repeating groups' in your customer table (google 'database normalization'). A more sensible way to structure this, assuming each order is made by only one customer, is to put CustomerID in the Order table instead of OrderID in the Customer table.

Answer (score 17):

You can use a [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) query to achieve this:

```
select CustomerID, count(*) as NumDuplicates
from Customer
group by CustomerID
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Also there is a success flag in the Orders table. I would like to get all the rows by customerID where orders table success flag is 1.

Comment: @nav100: You should update the question and add this new requirement. It changes the query.

Answer (score 5):

To see how many of each customer you have:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), CustName, CustomerID
from Customer
Group by CustName, CustomerID
```

You can use a `having` clause to limit to just duplicates:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), CustName, CustomerID
from Customer
Group by CustName, CustomerID
having count(*) > 1
```

**UPDATE**

To get those with successful orders:

```
select count(*), CustName, CustomerID
from(
  SELECT CustName, CustomerID
  from Customer, orders
  where customer.orderID = orders.orderID
  and orders.success = 1) subquery
group by subquery.CustName, subquery.CustomerID
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Here is the query I came up with. But it's 2 queries.

select customerID from Customer

select * from Orders where orderID in
      (select OrderId from Customer where customerID = 123456) 
                and success = 1

Answer (score 0):

```
select CustomerID, count(1)
  from Customer
 group by CustomerID
having count(1) > 1
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies: actually, this is counting the constant 1 not ordinal... (at least in SQL Server). In addition, what would SUM(1) do?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: 1 is used as a constant here.