# SQL query to return multiple records

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL query with duplicate records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152224/sql-query-with-duplicate-records)

Hi.

I am trying to write a query to return rows from Customer table for multiple orders.

Currently I am writing 2 queries to solve this problem. Is there anyway I can put it in one query?

```
//Get all customers
select customerID from Customer 

//For each customer
select * from Orders where orderID in
      (select OrderId from Customer where customerID = 123456) 
                and success = 1
```

Here is the table structure

```
Customer table 
----------------------------------------- 
orderID          CustName      CustomerID 
--------------------------------------- 
100               test           123456     
101               test           123456 


Orders table 
------------------------------------ 
pID               OrderID      Success
----------------------------------- 
1                 100            1
2                 101            1
```

Comment: If you post code (like your SQL) or XML or fixed tables / structures, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: similar to your recent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152224... are you doing *any* thinking for yourself?

Comment: How is this different from the question you posted a few minutes ago?

Comment: Why is there an orderid in the `CUSTOMER` table?  The tables should be related by `customerid`...

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.CustName, c.CustomerID, o.pID, o.OrderID
from Customer c
inner join Order o on c.orderID = o.OrderID
where o.Success = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.orderID, c.CustName, c.CustomerID, o.pID, o.OrderID, o.Success
FROM Customer c, Orders o
WHERE o.OrderID = c.orderID
```

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders JOIN Customers ON Orders.OrderID = Customers.orderID
```